# Average the color of remaining frames

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I've been seeing alot of images where it contains average color of each frame so I tried it myself.

This code will average the color of `x` amount of frames depending on the video's FPS.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

fcount = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
duration = fcount/fps

image = np.zeros((500, round(fcount/fps), 3), np.uint8)

print("FPS: %s, COUNT %s, DURATION %s" %(fps,fcount,duration))

frames = []

framespos = 0
framesprocessed = 0

framesremain = fcount % fps

while True:
    flag,frame = cap.read()
    if flag:
        avg_color_per_row = np.average(frame, axis=0)
        avg_colors = np.average(avg_color_per_row, axis=0)
        avg_color_int = np.array(avg_colors, dtype=np.uint8)
        frames.append(avg_color_int)
        if len(frames) == fps:
            image[:,[framespos]] = np.average(frames, axis=0)
            framespos += 1
            framesprocessed += fps
            print("%s/%s" %(framesprocessed,fcount))
            frames.clear()
    else:
        cv2.imwrite('averages.png',image)
        print("TOTAL FRAMES: %s, PROCESSED FRAMES %s, UNPROCESSED FRAMES %s" %(fcount,framesprocessed,fcount%fps))
        cap.release()
        break
```

This will write something like this:

[image: barcode]

This code works fine but it will not process all the frames. If `fcount % fps > 0`, those last frames wont get processed. How can I process those frames?

Answer (score 0):

I just added this code at `else` that checks if there's a remainder frames and also check if the `frames` array has contents then append the contents to `image` array.

```
if framesremain > 0 and len(frames) > 0:
    image[:,[framespos]] = np.average(frames, axis=0)
    framesprocessed += framesremain
    print("%s/%s" %(framesprocessed,fcount))
```